# How to move circle within specific region in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make floating joystick. for that i have use circle within circle.  I have made two separate xml files which contains images of small circle and large circle. I placed the small circle on the large circle. But when i am trying to drag large  circle, small circle doesn't move. so how should i combine this to images so if i drag large circle, small circle will also move with it.and i also want to move small circle but it shouldn't go outside of large circle.

here is my code:
first xml(large circle):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/layout_joystick"
    android:layout_width="314dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_button_bg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

second xml(small circle):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my java code:
         WindowManager wm;
         RelativeLayout mInview;
         RelativeLayout sball;

```
    RelativeLayout layout_joystick;
    ImageView innercircle;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();




        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater =     LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
       mInview = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.floatingwindow, null, false);
      sball=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner, null, false);

       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParameteres = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 700);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutPara = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300);

        mInview.setLayoutParams(layoutParameteres);
       sball.setLayoutParams(layoutPara);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                600, 400, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
       final WindowManager.LayoutParams para = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                200, 200, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
        parameters.x = 0;
        parameters.y = 0;




      Button     stop = new Button(this);
    stop.setText("Stop");
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        stop.setLayoutParams(btnParameters);

    mInview.addView(stop);

                 wm.addView(mInview, parameters);
           wm.addView(sball,para);
           sball.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = para;
                double x;
                double y;
                double pressedX;
                double pressedY;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            x = updatedParameters.x;
                            y = updatedParameters.y;

                            pressedX = event.getRawX();
                            pressedY = event.getRawY();

                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - pressedX));
                            updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - pressedY));

                            wm.updateViewLayout(sball, updatedParameters);

                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });






        mInview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = parameters;
            double x;
            double y;
            double pressedX;
            double pressedY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        x = updatedParameters.x;
                        y = updatedParameters.y;

                        pressedX = event.getRawX();
                        pressedY = event.getRawY();

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - pressedX));
                        updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - pressedY));

                        wm.updateViewLayout(mInview, updatedParameters);

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });





        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wm.removeView(mInview);
                stopSelf();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
    }




    }
```